# Misleading exception message in GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper with un-annotated parameters

Tags: spring-integration

The following code throws a `MessagingException` with message `At most one parameter (or expression via method-level @Payload) may be mapped to the payload or Message. Found more than one on method [public abstract java.lang.Integer org.example.PayloadAndGatewayHeader$ArithmeticGateway.add(int,int)]`.

```
@MessagingGateway
interface ArithmeticGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "add.input", headers = @GatewayHeader(name = "operand", expression = "#args[1]"))
    Integer add(@Payload final int a, final int b);

}
```

The desired functionality could be achieved with something like:

```
@MessagingGateway
interface ArithmeticGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "add.input", headers = @GatewayHeader(name = "operand", expression = "#args[1]"))
    @Payload("#args[0]")
    Integer add(final int a, final int b);

}
```

Should the first version also work? Nevertheless I believe the error message could be improved.

A sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/asigalas/spring-integration-tests). Please check org.example.PayloadAndGatewayHeader and org.example.PayloadAndGatewayHeaderTest.

**EDIT**

The purpose of `@GatewayHeader` was to show why one may want to have additional parameters that will not be part of the payload but I am afraid it created confusion. Here is a more streamlined example:

```
@MessagingGateway
interface ArithmeticGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "identity.input")
    Integer identity(@Payload final int a, final int unused);

}
```

Shouldn't the `unused` parameter be ignored since there is already another one that is annotated with `@Payload`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix parameter annotations (which are static) with expressions (which are dynamic) because the static code analysis can't anticipate what the dynamic expression will resolve to at runtime. It is probably unlikely, but there theoretically could be conditions in the expression. In any case, it can't determine at analysis time that the expression will provide a value for `#args[1]` at runtime (it could, of course for this simple case, but not all cases are this simple).

Use one or the other; use your second approach or

```
Integer add(@Payload final int a, @Header("operand") final int b);
```

Comment: Ignoring or dropping parameters is not currently supported when using annotations. Is there some business use case for this? It's never come up before.

Comment: I think it could be useful if it was possible to use a parameter to generate several headers. For example, one could use an un-annotated POJO parameter to populate several message headers. In my first example, think of `b` as a POJO and that there are multiple header definitions in the `@Gateway` annotation, all dependent on `b`.

Comment: That's possible today `#args[`].foo` and `#args[1].bar`. If there is some use case that can't be satisfied that way, please feel free to open a [new feature suggestion](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT); and contributions are welcome.